# Apple San Francisco font face in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, font-face

I want to implement an app using Flutter, and I want to use the system default font faces for Android and iOS.

The design I got to implement, has multiple font weights and I can't seem to find how to use other font weights for iOS devices (the font face being San Francisco), other than .Regular and .Bold. Is there a way to use multiple font weights and get them to be displayed when viewed on iOS devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

make sure to download the font pack with all weights and then declare the font weight after the font asset in pubspec.yaml like so :

```
- family: SanFrancisco
  fonts:
    - asset: fonts/SanFrancisco-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
```

Comment: if I do this, this would mean to use a custom font and both Android and iOS devices would use the SanFrancisco font face, no? If yes, then it doesn't help me because I don't want to use the same font face for both OS's.

Comment: if u attend to do this start wtith declaring all of your fonts and after that you can apply style by plaform within your code like so :                                                                           first import io : import 'dart:io'   and then  inside the style tag add this checker                                                                                                             Platform.isAndroid ? // Android style : // iOS style

Comment: It's not there in flutter by default?

Comment: @HassanAnsari Nope. It is not included in the Flutter SDK. Only SF UI is used not SF Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, Flutter presently utilizes the SF UI font instead of SF Pro (and related fonts), which is likely the font you anticipate. Currently, the only workaround is to import the font as a custom font, resulting in an increase in font size.

For updates on this matter, please refer to the following GitHub Issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63507